# Pre render page with getStaticProps throws ECONNRESET error

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api

I am trying to create a pre rendered page with next and getStaticProps function. For testing purpose I am using typicode. But getting ECONNRESET error.

`request to url failed, reason: read ECONNRESET`

```
function Home({data})
    return <p>Hello</p>
}

export async function getStaticProps(){
    const res = await fetch('url');
    const data = await res.json();

    return {
         props: {
             data
         }
    }
}

export default Home;
```

But if I write fetch call inside the component using `useEffect` it works as expected.

Comment: Is the URL you're trying to fetch from an external API or a Next.js API route?

Comment: External URL at https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users